# PostgreSql sorting by date breaks when record is updated

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I need a little help understanding this issue. I have a few replies sorted by date. Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE topic_replies (
  reply_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  author VARCHAR(30) REFERENCES users(username) ON DELETE CASCADE  NOT NULL,
  quote_body TEXT,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  topic_id BIGINT REFERENCES forum_topics(topic_id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL
)
```

When I'm querying data looks ordered but when I perform an update for a specific record data gets changed and the record updated is last in the list now.

```
  SELECT topic_replies.*, users.avatar as author_avatar, users.user_id as author_id,
  users.role as author_role, users.name as author_name FROM topic_replies
  LEFT JOIN users ON users.username = topic_replies.author
  WHERE topic_id = $1
  ORDER BY topic_replies.created_at DESC;
```

This is my query for updating the reply

```
UPDATE topic_replies
SET
body = $1
WHERE 
reply_id = $2
RETURNING *;
```

Keep in mind that when I'm updating the reply, `created_at` row is not getting changed so why the order is messed up?

initial order before updating

```
reply_id | created_at
------------+-----------------
4 | 2020-01-13
3 | 2020-01-12
2 | 2020-01-11
1 | 2020-01-10
(4 rows)
```

order after updating record

```
reply_id | created_at
------------+-----------------
4 | 2020-01-13
2 | 2020-01-11
1 | 2020-01-10
3 | 2020-01-12
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Your SELECT query (using `ORDER BY topic_replies.created_at`) will most definitely **not** sort the rows as shown.

Comment: Looks like the results shown after the update are from an unordered query.  An update will move the row to bottom of the list when no ordering is applied.

Comment: Both examples use a different order by than your query suggests: Ascending, not descending as it should. Check your SQL, there is something missing

Comment: @FrankHeikens, the second query is not using an `order by created_at`, look at the values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,  my bad, I was showing the result in ASC, I've fixed it now and displayed it in DESC but the root problem is still there. Why is not ordering correctly if I use ORDER BY. 

So after I'm updating, I use the same query again to SELECT the reviews but now the order it's messed up. Why ORDER BY is not working after updating record?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, after I'm updating the record I'm using the same query for selecting all the records, which contain ORDER BY. This is an issue that I do not understand, why ORDER BY doesn't get applied to the updated record?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, I'm using the same SELECT query for both results, after the update second result is not ordering correctly.

Comment: If you really use an ORDER BY in your SELECT, the result will **not** be sorted as shown.

Comment: The sort order is clearly the same even after the update, see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=08b2c209219e0d7082032d514108c302  - the only thing that could result in a "random order" is if you do _not_ use an ORDER BY

Comment: Is there an index or indexes on this table? If so have you tried a `REINDEX`? Where are you running the query in `psql` or some other client?